# Cannot enable spooler service from the command line. No online solutions have worked

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2016

I have a server 2016 core machine, Windows 10, that only has a command line to use. I need to install a printer on it, but it's giving an error saying that first I need to enable the spooler. I've tried doing this the following ways but nothing has worked. The computer says that it worked, but it still says that the service is stopped when I check:

- net start spooler (says it can't start because it is disabled)
- sc config spooler start= auto (responds with "[SC]
  ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS" but when I check it is still disabled
- Set-Service 'spooler' -StartupType Automatic
- Navigating to the service and running the .exe itself
- From another machine, I even tried: sc \(server) config spooler
  start= auto

Is there something I'm missing or doing incorrectly. Why is it saying that my command was successful when it isn't? Are there any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: This may have to do with the Registry key, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Spooler . You may need to take ownership and change permissions to enable changes.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install the Spooler. In Core pretty much nothing is installed besides the base OS, the "Core".

So, you have to install Print-Services, then you can set and activate the Spooler service.